# copying data from json response [Python]

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a scenario where I am trying to extract data from json response which is obtained from the GET request and then rebuilding the json data by changing some values and then sending a PUT request at same time after rebuilding the json data(i.e, after changing `idter` value)
below is the target json response.

```
target_json = {
  "name": "toggapp",
  "ts": [
    1234,
    3456
  ],
  "gs": [
    {
      "id": 4491,
      "con": "mno"
    },
    {
      "id": 4494,
      "con": "hkl"
    }
  ],
  "idter": 500,
  "datapart": false
}
```

from the above json I am trying to change the `idter` value to my custom value and rebuild it into json data again and post the new json data.
Here is what I have tried :

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + auth_token, 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
tesstid =[7865, 7536, 7789]
requiredbdy = []
for key in testid:
    get_metadata_targetjson= requests.get('https://myapp.com/%s' %key, headers = headers)
    metadata=get_metadata_target.json()
    for key1 in metadata:
        requiredbdy.append(
                {
                        "metadata" : [{
                        "name": key1['name'],
                        "ts": key1['ts'],
                      "gs": key1[gs],
                      "idter": 100,  #custom value which I want to change
                     "datapart": false
                     } ]
                    }
                  )
        send_metadata_newjson= requests.put('https://myapp.com/%s' %key, headers = headers data = requiredbdy)
        print(send_metadata_newjson.status_code)
```

Is this approach fine or How do I proceed in order to achieve this scenario.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better asked at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @stovfl Sorry I did not understand your point here to close this question

Comment: ***Is this approach fine or How do I proceed in order to achieve this scenario.***: Your question is my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module for this like so

```py
import json

my_json = """
{
  "name": "toggapp",
  "ts": [
    1234,
    3456
  ],
  "gs": [
    {
      "id": 4491,
      "con": "mno"
    },
    {
      "id": 4494,
      "con": "hkl"
    }
  ],
  "idter": 500,
  "datapart": false
}
"""

json_obj = json.loads(my_json)
json_obj['idter'] = 600
print(json.dumps(json_obj))
```

Prints

```
{"name": "toggapp", "ts": [1234, 3456], "gs": [{"id": 4491, "con": "mno"}, {"id": 4494, "con": "hkl"}], "idter": 600, "datapart": false}
```

Comment: thanks for that but I have to iterate through lot of id`s as I mentioned them in the list `tesstid =[7865, 7536, 7789]` and if you see I have used `for` loop regarding that purpose.
Also how do I send a PUT request taking the same `key` values after updating the JSON

Comment: `my_json` and the print are just to visualise the solution. To work this into your code, you would modify your `metadata` var as I did in this answer, then append the `dumps` value to `requiredbdy`.

Comment: I just realised that I would also omit `"datapart": false` this entire field from the target json to and my new json and also rename `name` key to `nameid` while sending PUT request should not have that field in the json itself do you know how can I do this using your  approach you mentioned.

Comment: You could use `json_obj.pop('datapart')`.

Comment: and about renaming `name` key to `nameid`

Comment: `json_obj['example'] = json_obj.pop('name')`, it creates a new key with the value of the old one, returned from `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

There's this small script used it to find entries in some very long and unnerving JSONs. not very beautifull und badly documented but maybe helps in your scenario.

```
from RecursiveSearch import Retriever

def alter_data(json_data, key, original, newval):
    '''
    Alter *all* values of said keys
    '''
    retr = Retriever(json_data)
    for item_no, item in enumerate(retr.__track__(key)): # i.e. all 'value'
        # Pick parent objects with a last element False in the __track__() result,
        # indicating that `key` is either a dict key or a set element
        if not item[-1]: 
            parent = retr.get_parent(key, item_no)
            try:
                if parent[key] == original:
                    parent[key] = newval
            except TypeError:
                # It's a set, this is not the key you're looking for
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alter_data(notification, key='value', 
               original = '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********',
               newval = '*UPDATED*')
```